# Curvature of different unit speed reparametrisations

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, curves, curvature

How do I prove that different unit speed reparametrisations of the same curve give same curvature?

I tried to consider two unit reparametrisations $\gamma_1(s)$ and $\gamma_2(u)$ where $u = \pm s + c$ where s is the arc length of $\gamma_1$ and c in some constant and then tried to show that $\dot\gamma_1 = \dot\gamma_2$. But I couldn't show it and I'm not even sure if it is the right condition. Any help in proving this would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to show that $\kappa_1=\|\dot\gamma_1\| = \|\dot\gamma_2\|=\kappa_2$. Use the chain rule $\frac{d\gamma_1}{ds}=\frac{d\gamma_2}{du}\cdot\frac{du}{ds}$